# Why I can't load most libraries in littler?

Tags: r, littler

I have a simple script `foo.R`, and inside it a single line:

```
library("argparse")
```

When I invoke the script from the bash shell I got the following error:

```
$r foo.R 
Error in library("argparse") : there is no package called ‘argparse’
```

OTOH, when I invoke Rscript, everyting seems fine:

```
$ Rscript foo.R 
Loading required package: proto
```

Why the difference? The littler README says nothing about problems with loading libraries.

I use 64 bit Linux Mint 15 (based on Ubuntu 13.04) with `R` (R version 3.0.2 (2013-09-25)) and `littler` (version 0.1.5) installed from Ubuntu universe apt repository (e.g. http://ftp.acc.umu.se/ubuntu/ubuntu/pool/universe/l/littler/)

Comment: I see no `littler` at CRAN. The last version at Dirk E's site is 2 years old.  I suggest you contact him directly to see if it's still supported.

Comment: What does `r -e '.libPaths()'` output?

Comment: @Peyton nothing. It simply returns nothing.

Comment: @CarlWitthoft Yes, you are right. I thought, that when installing it the apt-get showed me, that it was contacting the CRAN server. Apparentely I was mistaken. It must have been downloaded from the Ubuntu Universe repository.

Comment: @CarlWitthoft: Of course it is supported. I use it daily; the Ubuntu repo at CRAN gets fresh builds each time R is updated, and the Debian distro has a fine and healthy version too.  Please do some checks before spreading misinformation.

Comment: @DirkEddelbuettel  OK but it's not listed as a CRAN package, only hidden deep in the /bin/linux/ubuntu tree. Does this mean that Linux users are expected to use it only via apt-get or other in-system methods?

Comment: Correct.  Because it works from /usr/bin or /usr/local/bin where a CRAN package can never install, it never ever was CRAN package.  But it drives a number of cronjobs (eg CRANberries) and manual tasks each day.

Comment: I had this problem just now. I usually use zsh but I had to use bash to get littler to work properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your system it confused.  Here littler works just like a charm:

```
edd@max:~$ r -e'print(search())'
[1] ".GlobalEnv"   "Autoloads"    "package:base"
edd@max:~$ r -lMASS -e'print(search())'        
[1] ".GlobalEnv"        "package:MASS"      "package:utils"    
[4] "package:stats"     "package:graphics"  "package:grDevices"
[7] "Autoloads"         "package:base"    
edd@max:~$ r -lRcpp -e'print(search())'   
[1] ".GlobalEnv"      "package:Rcpp"    "package:methods" "Autoloads"     
[5] "package:base"   
edd@max:~$
```

I don't know about Mint, but you could try the Ubuntu repo at CRAN and get a pre-built littler.  Else just fetch the tarball and build it -- takes under a minute.  It does hardcode some configuration-time paths into the binary so the Mint build could be at fault.

On Debian and Ubuntu, however, everything is as it should be.

Comment: Well, on my system the output is _exactly_ the same. But still the script `library(argparse)` fails with `Error in library(argparse) : there is no package called ‘argparse’`, when the same works well with `Rscript`. If that is relevant, all libraries were installed as admin from `R` (not `r`). Maybe the `littler` stores library files in completely other location. But instalation of any package from within littler fails.

Comment: Yes, it does run on Vanilla Ubuntu 13.10 with no problems; no luck with vanilla Mint 15. I will send a bug then. Do you have any idea of what might be the source of the problem? The R itself works fine on Linux Mint 15.

Comment: It would appear that the prebuilt version of littler on Mint is buggy.   So install littler from source.